# data.table `:=` call stuck

Tags: r, data.table

I updated all my packages today via the RStudio package feature, which I haven't done for a while. After doing so, a line using `data.table`'s `:=` operator got stock in an endless loop. Please find a reproducible example below:

```
fun <- function(x, N, shift=0) {
  
  if (is.na(N==length(x))) {
    return(NA)
  }
  if (N==length(x)) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    x[(N+1+shift):(length(x)+shift)]
  }
}

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID  = rep(1:1000, each=100),
                 QTR = rep(1:100, times=1000),
                 vec = list(1:100))
#Stuck in endless calculation
DT[, vec2:=list(list(fun(x=unlist(vec), N=QTR, shift=-1))), by=list(ID,QTR)]
# Takes less than a second
DT[1:nrow(DT), vec2:=list(list(fun(x=unlist(vec), N=QTR, shift=-1))), by=list(ID,QTR)]
```

The first call keeps running and running for me within RStudio. If I select all rows in the second call (hence, in reality, not changing anything at all), it runs in less than a second.

My `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.13.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

My questions:

1. Is this issue specific to my set up or is someone else able to reproduce it?
2. In the latter case, is it because my code is incorrect or is that a bug in a new `data.table` version? I notice a note from data.table about it using 2 threads since 1.13.0, but looking at ?getDTthreads()` it is not clear to me if this is related and what I could/should change to make it work again.

Comment: I don't have the problem, R 3.6.3 and `data.table_1.12.8`

Comment: In the change log https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html#unreleased-data-table-v1-13-1-in-development-, bug fix 3 mentions a regression in performance with lists. Try upgrading to `1.13.1` perhaps. I have `1.12.8` and also can't replicate it

Comment: I can replicate on R 4.0.2 and `data.table_1.13.0`

Comment: Thank you all for checking. @JonnyPhelps I updated to 1.13.1 and that solved indeed the issue. So it seems to be a bug in 1.13.0 (as sindri_baldur could replicate it, too), which is already solved. Jonny Do you want to post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad the update resolved it!

Comment from the post:

In the change log https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html#unreleased-data-table-v1-13-1-in-development-, bug fix 3
mentions a regression in performance with lists. Try upgrading to
1.13.1 perhaps. I have 1.12.8 and also can't replicate it